# Converting String to it's integer ascii values

Tags: java, string, integer, ascii, numberformatexception

I'm stuck at the very end of my problem getting a **NumberFormatException**.

I want to take a string such as **Wsup**, and turn it into its `ASCII` values with the result, '87115117112'.

I've gotten that string of numbers built successfully a couple different ways, but when I try to `parseInt(string)` on it, I get my exception. I've tried printing out the string as an array of characters to look for hidden white space, I've used `String.trim()` with no luck, I'm quite confused why it isn't recognized as a valid integer.

```
public static int toAscii(String s){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String ascString = null;
    long asciiInt;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
                sb.append((int)s.charAt(i));
                char c = s.charAt(i);
            }
            ascString = sb.toString();
            asciiInt = Integer.parseInt(ascString); // Exception here
            return 0;// asciiInt;    0 in place just to run
}
```

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: ignore that char c = s.char... Remnant of another way I tried

Comment: 87115117112 does not fit a 32 bit integer (signed or unsigned).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yor **asciiInt** is long type so do it in this way

```
  asciiInt =  Long.parseLong(ascString);
```

here is your full function

```
public static long toAscii(String s){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String ascString = null;
        long asciiInt;
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
                    sb.append((int)s.charAt(i));
                    char c = s.charAt(i);
                }
                ascString = sb.toString();
                asciiInt = Long.parseLong(ascString);
                return asciiInt;
    }
```

Comment: +1 Also, make sure you are returning a `long` and not an `int` (`public static long toAscii(String s)`)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I had recognized my result as not fitting for type int, which is why I changed asciiInt to long, but I didn't follow up accordingly. Code's all set, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to return as long not as integer I have implement your toAscii() with little bit

```
public static long toAscii(String s){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        long asciiInt;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            asciiInt = (int)c; 
            System.out.println(c +"="+asciiInt);
            sb.append(asciiInt);
        }
        return Long.parseLong(sb.toString());
}
```